# SQL em Genexus e GxFlow

Tags: sql, genexus, workflow

É possível retornar o resultado de uma consulta SQL em transação do Genexus?

Preciso criar um WorkFlow através do Genexus, onde utilizando o DBRET, eu consegui ler os dados de um BD externo e agora preciso retornar algumas informações no GxFlow.

Consegui fazer com que o flow retorne todos os dados através das transações importadas do BD externo, mas preciso consultar individualmente cada item do BD e retornar o resultado na Inbox do gxFlow.

No meu caso é um sistema de HelpDesk de terceiros que estou consultando no Genexus, e quero controlar as informações dos chamados, através do GxFlow.
Preciso fazer com que o Flow gere um novo registro na Inbox, sempre que houver o registro de um novo chamado na ferramenta externa.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já presenciou ou necessitou de algo desse tipo?

Desde já agradeço e aguardo respostas!
Obi

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia André,

Se eu entendi bem a sua necessidade, você quer que ao gerar um registro em uma tabela de um sistema terceiro (que você mapeou via DBRet), gera uma nova instância no GXFlow. Se for isso, entendo que possa ser feito de duas formas:

1. Webnotification
2. Trigger de banco ou Webservice

Se for feito via webnotification, deves ter em conta que o browser deverá estar ativo (receptor) para que a ação de gerar uma nova instância seja realizada. Para suprir uma possível necessidade de não estar com o browser ativo, podes criar uma rotina de tempos em tempos verificar se há algum registro novo que não gerou a instância

A segunda solução entendo que seja mais simples, mas não sei se é viável, pois precisará dar manutenção do lodo do sistema do terceiro, seja criando uma trigger no banco dele ou seja ele chamando um WS seu.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa em contate no email gx2@gx2.com.br